# Prove that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that $\int_a^b|f-g| \lt \epsilon$

Tags: integration, functions, continuity, riemann-integration

Assume that $f$ is Riemann-integrable on the interval $[a,b]$ and $\epsilon$ is a positive number.

Prove that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that $\int_a^b|f-g| \lt \epsilon$ .

Note : The problem is the existence of the function. I don't know how to show it. Any hint or clue would be useful. An answer would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Approximate $f$ by step functions. Then approximate step functions by continuous functions.

Comment: Riemann integrable means the area under $f$ can be approximated arbitrarily well by rectangles. Take the tops of these rectangles collectively as a function (a sum of step functions), and make them continuous by connecting the step functions by drawing a line between successive ones.

Comment: Related: [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem and Riemann Integrable functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019595/weierstrass-approximation-theorem-and-riemann-integrable-functions) ; [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem for continuous functions on open interval](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365346/weierstrass-approximation-theorem-for-continuous-functions-on-open-interval)